# MVC4 Ajax form post-back with multiple dropdownlists sets selection equal on all

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I am at a wits end, and need some pointers where to look.

I have a MVC Ajax form as follows:

```
<div id="totalPartial">
    <table>
        @foreach (Application application in Model.Applications)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => application.Candidate.Client.ClientName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => application.Candidate.FirstName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => application.Test.TestName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @{ Model.SelectedSession = application.Session; }
                    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Plan", "Keuring",
                                           new AjaxOptions
                                               {
                                                   InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                                                   UpdateTargetId = "totalPartial",
                                                   HttpMethod = "POST"
                                               },
                                           new {id = "form" + application.Id, name = "form" + application.Id}))
                    {
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => application.Id)
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => application.Session.Id, Model.SessionsInclNotPlanned, new {@class = "sessiondropdown", onchange = "$(this.form).submit()"})
                    }
                </td>
            </tr>
        }        
    </table>
</div>
```

Every time a table row is added on iteration, a dropdownlist is generated, with the relevant session selected. Works as a charm - when loaded initally.

When the user selects a different session, there is a ajax call to replace the current table (hence update totalPartial). Works with a catch.
In this postback the selected value in all of the dropdownboxes are the same as the selected one (they should keep their own value). The selected value is actively set in the methods:

```
@{ Model.SelectedSession = application.Session; }
   Model.SessionsInclNotPlanned
```

On a full reload - it works again as a charm. Just in this Ajax- postback, the initiating selection gets propagated on all list boxes...

where to look? I checked fiddler, and the return from the Ajax request is as displayed (wrongly) in the browser, so the error occurs on server side. Still - When I debug the inputs in the listbox, it reads correctly.

Comment: You are saying...........

 I checked fiddler, and the return from the Ajax request is as displayed (wrongly) in the browser, so the error occurs on server side. Still - When I debug the inputs in the listbox, it reads correctly.

Can you identify what server error you are getting? If you are not able to break application on exception or error then enable CLR Exception from Debug-Exceptions. 

Need more information on this as you are 100% sure there is error on server side code.

Comment: @Vincent can you show your ajax request that bind the `DropDownListFor` in your view.